# Mongoose & MongoDB connection on production

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

What are best practicies to handle mongodb connection using mongoose on production? 
This is my code

**connectToDatabase.js**

```
'use strict';
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const mongodb = require('mongodb');
mongoose.Promise = require('bluebird');
const { Db, Server } = mongodb;

const database = 'test';

const connectToDatabase = (callback) => {
  if (process.env.NODE_ENV == 'test') return false;

  const db = new Db(database new Server('localhost', 27017));
  db.open()
    .then(() => {
      mongoose.connect(`mongodb://localhost/${database}`, { config: { autoIndex: false } });
        mongoose.connection
          .once('open', () => {
            console.log(`Connected to database ${database}`);
            callback(db);
          })
          .on('error', (error) => {
            console.warn('Warning', error);
          });
  });
};

module.exports = connectToDatabase;
```

**app.js**

```
const connectToDatabase = require('./connectToDatabase');

connectToDatabase(() => {
  // run server 
});
```

I don't know exactly what happening when connection to database is interrupted, Is mongoose trying connect to database again?